# Delphi Thread and TCriticalSection

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I encounter some strange behaviors with threads so I guess there is something I'm doing wrong or something I don't understand.

My application (Delphi Berlin) has two processes : a service and a console app. They communitcate via socket (Indy).

Each process has a thread dedicated to communication.

I use TCriticalSection when I need to read/write variables used by main thread and by communication Thread.

I also make intensive usage of log. The log can be written (one log file by process) by main thread and by communication thread.

So what I'm doing when I want to write a trace in log file is to use a variable TCriticalSection to prevent main thread and commmunication thread to write to the log file at the same time:

```
Procedure TApp.trace(logLevel : byte; procName , pi_str: string);
var F: textfile;
    LogFileName: String;
    vl_log : Boolean;
    vc_LogHeader : String;
    th, thcurrent : TTh;
begin
    if GetLog() then begin // False if log is deactivated
        for th := Low(TTh) to High(TTh) do begin
            if TThread.CurrentThread.ClassName = ThreadsLog.Name[th] then begin
                thcurrent := th;
                break;
            end;
        end;
        if ThreadsLog.LogLevel[thcurrent] < logLevel then exit;

        LogFileName := gc_tmp + WinProc.Name[WHO_AM_I] + '.log';
        vc_LogHeader := '[' + GetLogTime + ' ' + ThreadsLog.Name[thcurrent] + ' ' + procName + ' ' + IntToStr(logLevel) + ']';
        if Length(vc_LogHeader) < 60 then vc_LogHeader := vc_LogHeader + StringOfChar (' ', 60 - Length(vc_LogHeader) );

        LockTrace.Acquire;
        try
            try
                {$IFDEF MACOS}
                    AssignFile(F, LogFileName, CP_UTF8);
                {$ELSE}
                    AssignFile(F, LogFileName);
                {$ENDIF}
                if FileExists(LogFileName) then Append(F) else Rewrite(F);
                {$IFDEF MACOS}
                    Writeln(F, UTF8String(vc_LogHeader + AnsiString(pi_str)));
                {$ELSE}
                    Writeln(F, vc_LogHeader + pi_str);
                {$ENDIF}
                CloseFile(F);
            except
                on e : exception do begin
                    dbg(LogFileName + ' ' + e.Message);
                end;
            end;
        finally
            lockTrace.Release;
        end;
    end;
end;

function TApp.GetLog() : boolean;
begin
    gl_logLock.Acquire;
    try
        result := gl_log;
    finally
        gl_logLock.Release;
    end;
end;
```

However sometimes, some lines are not written to the file.
But dbg(LogFileName + ' ' + e.Message) does not execute cause it is supposed to write in another log file and this file stays empty. So no exception seems to be fired.

Is it possible to use TCriticalSection this way ?
What I understand about TCriticalSection, is that it puts a lock so others threads trying to put their own lock have to wait until it is released. Is that right ?

I guess I can use one variable or several variables TCriticalSection. If I use only one variable, there will be more cases where a lock exists so more time to wait. If I use one TCriticalSection per shared variable, there will be less locks so better performances. Is it right ?

Thanks for any correction or clarification.

Comment: Where is `LockTrace` declared and how is it instantiated?

Comment: LockTrace is a member of a class that also has the thread as a member. It is instanciate in the constructor of the this class via TCriticalSection.Create.

Comment: So, LockTrace is a member of TApp and there are multiple instances of TApp in the application during runtime or only one?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to use the same TCriticalSection for all objects writing to your log file, otherwise, the log will get out of order..

Comment: There is only one TApp object.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with your code, not all thread / critical section related.

---

```
function TApp.GetLog() : boolean;
begin
    gl_logLock.Acquire;
    try
        result := gl_log;
    finally
        gl_logLock.Release;
    end;
end;
```

The above lock code is useless it doesn't provide any protection whatsoever. Reading a boolean variable is already atomic. It's also symptomatic of a common misunderstanding of how to make code thread-safe.

- Locks are intended to protect access to ***data***.
- The above pattern is often ***incorrectly*** used to protect access to an object.
- But once the calling code is able to start ***using*** the object, you're already outside the lock.
- I.e the underlying ***data*** of the object is no longer protected from concurrent thread access.

---

```
for th := Low(TTh) to High(TTh) do begin
    if TThread.CurrentThread.ClassName = ThreadsLog.Name[th] then begin
        thcurrent := th;
        break;
    end;
end;
if ThreadsLog.LogLevel[thcurrent] < logLevel then exit;
```

In the above, if the loop ever ends without the **if** condition evaluating to `True`, `thcurrent` will be uninitialised leading to undefined behaviour. Anything from AV exceptions to things just not behaving as you'd expect.

Quite possibly `ThreadsLog.LogLevel[thcurrent] < logLevel` could evaluate to `True` (and `Exit`) without triggering an AV for some undefined values of `thcurrent`.

Also note that looping through your threads and doing string comparisons is a pretty inefficient way to check your current thread. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but you should be able to figure certain things out simply from the current thread id.

---

You say `dbg(LogFileName + ' ' + e.Message);` is not called. Well there are many reasons it might not be called. You'll have to figure out which (1 or multiple) apply.

- You could `Exit` early.
- `GetLog()` might return `False`.
- Any exception before the **try..except** block won't get there.
- If you've disabled IO errors, an exception won't be raised by old-style file operations. You would have to manually check them using [`IOResult`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_IOResult.html).
- And of course `dbg` might be called, but could itself also fail in some way.

Comment: Useless to protect read/write for a boolean ? So nothing can goes wrong when a thread tries to read while another change the value ? About "if ThreadsLog.LogLevel[thcurrent] < logLevel then exit;" , I of course tried commenting this line before posting. It does not change anything so it's not related. I also forced GetLog to return true. Same problem.

Comment: @user2244705 Yes _useless_. A single read is atomic. If another thread writes to `gl_logLock` around the same time, one of 2 things happen: 1) write is 1st, read is 2nd. 2) Or read is 1st, write is 2nd. ... The only difference with locks is: Whichever thread is second to try acquire the lock might be blocked and get context switched out. The OS will grant time to other threads and switch back shortly after the lock is released. The block usually only lasts a few milliseconds (_unless a bug elsewhere in your code fails to release the lock correctly_). So ***yes that lock is useless.***

Comment: @user2244705 Note: Locking is required when the operation on the data is ***not atomic***. E.g. Read the bool, make a decision based on what you read and write a value back. `gl_logLock := not gl_logLock;` (A) If 2 threads run that statement in serial, the value will toggle twice returning back to its original value. (B) If 2 threads run in parallel, there's a possibility that the 1st thread reads, the 2nd thread reads, then each thread locally perform **not** and both write back the ***same value***! I.e. a race condition bug.

Comment: @user2244705 Finally, you've tested 2 of the 5 things I pointed out; what about the others? Also, these are things based on the code you presented. There are other possibilities that could come into play in other code you haven't presented. … E.g. a locking bug such as a deadlock that causes a logging attempt to be blocked at one of your 2 `lock.Acquire;` calls. Or you might have a bug that means `trace` isn't called when you expect it to be called.

Comment: Thanks for clarification about boolean read. Of course I checked all locks are well released, and they are. I will invesitgate around write exceptions and move the loop in the try/except.

Comment: For those who downvoted the question, I wonder how many Dephi developpers have a perfect mastery of the subject. I asked a clarification because I was not sure of the way to use critical sections. I got it. And I'm pretty sure that I'm not alone.

Comment: @user2244705 I can only guess the down-voters reasons. But they probably consider the question itself of poor quality: your sample code cannot be used to reproduce your problem. So it fails C and V of: [mcve]. It also has a fair amount of extraneous detail not relevant to multi-threading or critical sections (failing M). I'm actually certain your bug has nothing to do with multi-threading. Your code and analysis do demonstrate some misunderstandings which hopefully my answer clears up. But I seriously doubt you're getting down-voted based on your knowledge of Delphi.

Comment: To reproduce the problem in this case, I should provide almost all the application code. Because Indy sockets and all the specific logic of the communications between the two processes was involved in the bug. I was pretty sure the origin was my misundertanding of TCriticalSection and indeed it was. I had tons of locks for boolean variables, now not anymore. And I now use a lock variable per data (I thought I could use only a lock variable per thread...). Finally, I found the bug was a simple deadlock. So thanks Craig for this very useful clarification.

Comment: @user2244705 Ooh! Interesting that you mention "lock variable per thread" because that's highly ineffective given that a lock's purpose is to say: "Here's a shared piece of data. Any thread's wanting to use it _should_ check with me. You can wait here till it's safe to proceed, but please remember to let me know when you're done." (Note the ***"should"***; unfortunately nothing about locks prevents rogue code from ignoring the lock. Which is why encapsulation is such an important technique.)

Comment: PS: Something to bear in mind is that: fine-grained locks provide more opportunity for concurrency. But conversely, the more locks there are in your application, the more blocking and slow-downs occur (and higher deadlock risks). So there is a bit of a balancing act required. However, if you can design a solution that can break work down into smaller pieces ***without sharing data***, that's the first prize!